# Getting the value from viewstate, in case the session expires

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a lot of pages in my project. In all pages I write:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{     
   if (HttpContext.Current.Session["curUserRole"] == null)
   {
      DBUsers.SetUserStatusOnline("0", ViewState["curUserLogin"].ToString());
      ViewState["curUserLogin"] = "";
      Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
   }
   else
   {       
      ViewState["curUserLogin"] = HttpContext.Current.Session["curUserLogin"].ToString();
      DBUsers.SetUserStatusOnline("1", ViewState["curUserLogin"].ToString());
   }
}
```

When a user logs in on the site, the current user role is written into the session and the current user login is written in the viewstate. When the session finishes, I thought that I could view the current user login in the viewstate and set the offline status in the database. But when `session` is null, the viewstate also null. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to `UnhandledException`'s answer, I would also add that it might be better to centralize your logic in a class and then derive your pages from that new class rather than cut-and-pasting it to every page:

```
public class MyPageClass : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Add your logic here.

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}

public class WebPage1 : MyPageClass
{  
    private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: ok. How I can save user login and call this method when any page reload and session is null?

Comment: My answer was a suggestion on how to centralize your logic rather than cut-and-pasting it to every page. You need to look at `UnhandledException`'s answer for addressing the issue of a null `ViewState` when redirecting from another page.

Comment: @DarienFawkes - While I appreciate the rep, I don't think my answer solves your problem. Didn't `UnhandledException`'s answer fix your issue? If so, you should really accept his answer.

Answer (score 2):

If `Response.redirect` is used, then ViewState cannot be accessed across pages. try using `Server.transfer`

check [Access ViewState Across Pages](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37753/Access-ViewState-Across-Pages) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't using [Forms Authentication](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/introduction/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-cs) be a better approach rather than manually handling roles, viewstate and session?

That way you'd interact with the current [Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810496/forms-authentication-understanding-context-user-identity) to get user information, rather custom storage of information.

And I think you probably shouldn't depend on a postback by the user to determine if the session has expired. What if the user simply closes the browser? He/she would remain "Online" indefinitely.

You should provide a mechanism for the user to manually log out.

Now, if you are using [InProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) for your session state you can handle Session_End in global.asax to set that user to "Offline" in your database.
If you are using StateServer or SQLServer then Session_End is not called on timeout, and you have to handle it in a custom way, such as through a scheduled task on the DB Server to mark users as Offline.

Now, if you really need a very precise control of the Online/Offline status, you might need to go for a more complex approach. One option would be, that whenever a user executes any action, to store a datetime on that last activity on the User table. And consider any user that hasn't done any activity in a specific time to be offline.
Another option would be ajax calls used as a keep-alive call to update that datetime mentioned above.