# Why is Context.User.Identity.Name always empty?

Tags: c#, webforms, httpcontext

`Context.User.Identity.Name` is always empty, currently I am using WebForms:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("jamal");
cookie.Value = "bilal";
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Here I want username:

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    AddUser(Context.User.Identity.Name, this.Context.ConnectionId);
}

private static void AddUser(String username, String connectionId)
{
    ISet<String> connections;

    if (users.TryGetValue(username, out connections) == false)
    {
        connections = users[username] = new HashSet<String>();
    }

    connections.Add(connectionId);
}
```

Comment: Where do you call the `Context.User.Identity.Name` ? Also, is the user authenticated?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you haven't required authentication for this action.
Require that the user is authorized for the action by decorating it with the `Authorize` attributeclass - which will initiate the authentication negotiation. 
I never tried with webform but it should work if you add in the web config this rule:

```
<authentication mode="Forms" />
```

Comment: <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/UserInterface/WebFormLogin" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

Answer (score 0):

Try to call this on Page_Load event, you are probably calling it too soon.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are creating your cookie, it is not an authentication cookie. Asp.net handles the authentication process for you if you create a new asp.net web forms project. But if you want to create your own authentication cookie, [these are the steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217105/how-can-i-manually-create-a-authentication-cookie-instead-of-the-default-method) that you have to follow.

The [FormsAuthenticationModule](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-cs) from asp.net authenticates the user by checking the authentication ticket. Your cookie has only one name. You have to create the ticket. [Also check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810496/forms-authentication-understanding-context-user-identity).